# Get list of ECL Ice portal images

Tags: ecl, ecl-connector

In our Tridion CMS, we are using ECL to connect to Ice Portal (our third-party multimedia assets provider). How do you get the list of eclUris of all the available assets?

We tried getting the list by using the following code snippet.

```
IEclSession eclSession = SessionFactory.CreateEclSession(username);
var idList = eclSession.GetContententLibraryUris(pubId);
```

But we only received one ECL id. Are there other ways to get the list?

Comment: Is it a security thing? have you tried running it with admin user? are you running it in child publication and this item Is localized?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few options:

1. Enumerate items through the folder structure. The same item might show up in multiple folders, but you can just filter out duplicates. This will work with any provider, but will be slow. But then - anything getting huge lists will be slow.
2. Do a wild card search giving all items, then paginate through the results (provider needs to allow this search of course).
3. Talk to the ICE portal API directly. You will need to figure out how the ECL URIs are encoded, but that is typically not hard unless the provider implementer want it to be hard.
4. Now we are into speculation, and there might be something preventing this from working... but it SHOULD work if you can modify the provider: Create a special folder URI (for example using the folder id "chucknorriscangetallitems" in the ECL URI) - then in the provider method getting the items of a folder, return all items when this id is seen.